# How to make a variable in `protractor.conf.js` available in spec file?

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, protractor, e2e

I have a variable in `protractor.conf.js` which is exported within `onPrepare()` function as: `global.myVariable = myVariable`, and in spec file I'am trying to use/call it, but it seems that it can't be accessible and isn't available for the spec file.

Error:

**`E/launcher - Error: Error: Cannot find module 'myVariable'`**

It's being treated as it would be an npm module and can't be found in npm_modules which is correct.

`myVariable` is actually an object build by a constructor function within `protractor.conf.js`

How can make it accessible from the `spec` file?

Comment: Vincent, would you care to explain in which scenarios you needed to expose  a variable globally and access directly in the spec file, as generally it is considered a bad practice .

Comment: And in case if you have to do it, have it in separate globals.js file and keep config.js light.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal: Sure, I can add more input and info regarding the background of my question... I'll update my question then.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal: Sorry for the late answer! here is the background of my question: I do have a test case where a user registers via UI and then gets an email in the inbox. The email contains a registration confirmation link. I'am using a `mailListener` library and its initialization is being done in `protractor.config.js` as: `var MailListener = require("mail-listener2"); var mailListener = new MailListener({....})`. Therefor I have to pass a variable `global.mailListener = mailListener` to `*.spec.ts` file and then invoke a method on it.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal: Now I'am facing other issue if you could help! Here is the issue I'am dealing with right now: [E2E: Retrieve email-link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/31856/e2e-retrieve-email-link-how-to-invoke-callback-function-for-maillistener)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue fixed... solution is:

```
params: {
    myVariable: function () {
        ...
        ...
    },
    otherProperty: 'Value'
}
```

and this how you can reach in `spec` files:

`browser.params.myVariable` or `browser.params.otherProperty`

with this we can make a variable accessible from `protractor.conf.js` to `spec` test files.
The following [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203398/protractor-set-global-variables) was helpful and also the [protractor doc](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts) where it's explaining the property: `params?: any;`

Comment: This works for getPageTimeout , but any other variable e.g serverURL, doesnt work

Comment: @DhananjaySonar, Could you pls. add more details? It should normally work for any other variable.

Answer (score 0):

I just put a config in my `protractor.conf.js`  with a variable named  `getPageTimeout`   and then in my `spec.ts` I can reference it with `browser.getPageTimeout`

[image]

Wierd though that I had to set the timeout in the Cucumber framework rather than the Jasmine/Protractor framework.  I don't quite understand why.