# How to import and use Angular Environment variables in `protractor.config`?

Tags: protractor, angular

I would like to save some credentials in the angular `environment.prod` file and pass them to `protractor.config.js`

Is it possible to import and use env variables from the Angular app environments files.

I did create a normal JavaScript file containing an object and pass it to the `protractor.config.js`:

```js
    var userAccess = require('./src/protractor_env.js');
    ....
    ....
    console.log(userAccess.mail);
```

It's working fine, but I would like to use the `environment.prod.ts` built-in file... is this possible and would it be a good practice?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Good question! My bad, I didn't mention this. Following: I do have a function in `protractor.config.js` inside `onPrepare()` function where I use an access for google mail. I would like to remove those credentials from this file and make them available in the environment file. For more details, pls. see this question: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/31856/e2e-retrieve-email-link-how-to-invoke-callback-function-for-maillistener from me.